# Laravel 5 Auth::attempt not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

After running php artisan tinker I create an User:

```
App\User::create(['email' => 'test@test.com', 'password' => '123456'])
=> App\User {#723
     email: "test@test.com",
     updated_at: "2015-10-13 17:33:58",
     created_at: "2015-10-13 17:33:58",
     id: 6,
   }
```

Why does the following command return false?

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => 'test@test.com', 'password' => '123456'])
=> false
```

How shall Auth::attempt be used?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel uses bcrypt to hash passwords. If you create the user following way:

```
App\User::create(['email' => 'test@test1.com', 'password' => bcrypt(123456)]);

Auth::attempt(['email' => 'test@test1.com', 'password' => '123456']);
```

will work.